# Regular Expression to find values between quotes

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a regular expression to find values between quotes:

```
([\"'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1
```

This works fine, however, if there are double quotes between quote, then it fails and split them too. for example.

```
"value1","value2","value with "" is here","value4"
```

I need output like

```
value1
value2
value with "" is here
value4
```

that means, if the double quote appears somewhere, it should return that in output. 
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first idea was to allow double quotes by adding them to your alternation:

```
([\"'])(?:\\\1|\1\1|.)*?\1
```

However, since you've made your quantifier lazy, this will still not quite work. Better make it explicit that unescaped quotes are not permitted between quotes:

```
([\"'])(?:\\\1|\1\1|(?!\1).)*\1
```

See it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yE6cQ0).

**Explanation:**

```
([\"'])   # Match a quote, remember which kind in group 1.
(?:       # Start non-capturing group:
 \\\1     # Either match a backslash-escaped quote
|         # or
 \1\1     # a doubled quote
|         # or
 (?!\1)   # (as long as it's not a quote)
 .        # any character.
)*        # Repeat as necessary
\1        # Match a corresponding quote
```

Comment: Yeah, it was a part of the CSV file. Yes, your provided expression works '([\"'])(?:\\\1|\1\1|(?!\1).)*\1'  however the other expression doesn't. But I am glad and thankful to you that I got a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your input looks like a CSV record, in which a literal quote is escaped by adding another quote.  Are you saying you can also escape a quote with a backslash?  I've never seen that; it's usually one or the other.  And I've never seen a CSV variant that let you alternate between single-quotes (apostrophes) or double-quotes in the same record.  It's possible you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Assuming only double-quotes are recognized as  field delimiters, and that they can only be escaped by adding another quote, matching a field is as simple as can be:

```
(?:"[^"]*")+
```

The backslash-escape version is a little more complicated:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

If you single-quote delimiters are allowed as well, the easiest way is to add another alternative:

```
(?:"[^"]*")+|(?:'[^']*')+

"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'
```

And if you really need to support both kinds of quote and both kinds of escaping, see Tim's answer.  But I'm extremely skeptical.

Comment: Yeah, it was a part of the CSV file. Yes, your provided expression works (?:"[^"]*")+|(?:'[^']*')+  Both of your and @time-pietzcker provided correct solutions. I am not sure how to mark both answers as "answer". Seems I can mark only one.